# apple watch にアプリアイコンを表示する方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, watchkit

iOSアプリのアプリアイコンと同じ画像を、Apple Watch のpush通知に表示される画像にも設定するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 関連: [apple watch にアプリアイコンが表示されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44209/19110)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode を起動して AppIcon asset から設定できます。

[Notification icon missing on Apple Watch in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383403/notification-icon-missing-on-apple-watch-in-ios-11)

が参考になるかと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]